# In React component, how to make <span> in a clickabel and call the function of this react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react component MyComp, 
I have a parsed markdown text, I want to make all span in this text clickable and call a function of MyComp.

I use this sentence to achieve it, but it can only call a global javascript function.

`let clickableSub = sub.replace(/<span>/g, '<span onclick="showDict(this)">')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **event delegation**. Bind the event handler to the container where you render the markdown into and then check whether the event originates on a `<span>` element. E.g.

```
function handler(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    console.log(event);
  }
}

function MyComp({html}) {
  return <div onClick={handler} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks so much! This problem made me crazy in these days.